# Availability of metering water timers

Tags: watering

When I was a child, my mother had a handy mechanical device that could be hooked to standard garden hose fittings.  You turned the knob to the number of gallons you wanted to dispense and it would automatically turn off after that amount had passed through.  It was useful for certain applications where the amount of water was important, but the delivery rate was not constant and/or it needed to sit in readiness for a while, but then only dispense a particular amount of water once activated.

These days everyone seems to use simple timers, whether mechanical or electronic, and I can't find such a metering device anywhere.  I can find valves with no meter, and meters with no valves, but come up completely dry when I look for meters that shut the water off.  I do have the skills to manufacture one myself, but that would be quite a bit of effort, and I'd rather avoid kludging it all together just to have somebody tell me that I could have just purchased one for half the price of the parts...

Does anybody still make such a contraption?  Or does everyone really just use timers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are combined now a days: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CWC3CFE/ref=psdc_553988_t2_B007NHS9M4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CWC3CFE)

Comment: Wow they did a good job of making that description confusing...  Fortunately one of the reviewers mentions that it goes by amount and the time's just an estimate.  I'd seen these in passing, but the description sounds like it's a timer with a flow-control valve, so I missed that it was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Perkins Np, hey it may sound trivial but it helps close topics if you could just hit the green accepted arrow on my response!

Comment: I will.  I just generally give things at least four hours in case someone has a really ingenious answer up their sleeve.  You're too quick for your own good.  ;)